# How to run CUPS in docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cups

I want to run cups in docker.

My Dockerfile:

```
ARG LIB_VERSION
FROM buffer-connectors-base:"${LIB_VERSION}"
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install cups -y
COPY app/requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
COPY app/ .
CMD cupsd
```

If I try sent `lpstat -p` in image, I receive:

```
root@021034ef2cda:/app# lpstat -p
lpstat: Bad file descriptor
```

If I run cups directly in image, it works!

```
root@021034ef2cda:/app# cupsd
root@021034ef2cda:/app# lpstat -p
lpstat: No destinations added.
```

After this I can install printer

```
root@021034ef2cda:/app# lpadmin -p HP-TEST -E -v ipp://192.168.18.193 -m everywhere
root@021034ef2cda:/app# lpstat -p
printer HP-TEST is idle.  enabled since Tue Sep 20 13:51:58 2022
```

How do I write the instruction to run cups in Dockerfile correctly?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/olbat/cupsd

Comment: @Boney thank you! I saw it but I'm wondering if it's possible to install and run cups in about the same way as I described in the question. Why does cups run inside an image but not from dockerfile?

Comment: When you say "in image", what command are you actually running to get that prompt?  Normally a Docker container won't have access to host devices like printers, so it will be hard to run a printer daemon in a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze if I coorect understood your question (my English is not perfect) I use `docker exec -ti <image_name> "/bin/bash"`
I use it only for checking that all work correctly