# How to run script in docker without exiting

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

First of all, yes, I've seen similar questions around, yet I haven't seen one that particular addresses my needs.

I used to have a `Dockerimage` which successfully created a container:

```
FROM php:8.1.12-fpm

ARG uid=1000
ARG user=inigomontoya

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip \
    supervisor

# Install and enable xDebug
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install php modules required by laravel.
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan commands.
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create directory for supervisor logs
RUN mkdir -p "/etc/supervisor/logs" && chmod -R 775 "/etc/supervisor/logs"

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy supervisor config files
COPY ./docker/config/supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf


USER $user
```

then I was in need of adding some extra packages: `cups` and `cups-pdf`. So I added the packages needed and created a `startup.sh` script which would be in charge of running `cups`, then my `Dockerfile` looked like the following:

```
FROM php:8.1.12-fpm

ARG uid=1000
ARG user=inigomontoya

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip \
    supervisor \
    cups \
    cups-pdf

# Install and enable xDebug
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install php modules required by laravel.
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan commands.
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create directory for supervisor logs
RUN mkdir -p "/etc/supervisor/logs" && chmod -R 775 "/etc/supervisor/logs"

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy supervisor config files
COPY ./docker/config/supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

COPY cupsd.conf /etc/cups/cupsd.conf

COPY startup.sh startup.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "startup.sh"]

USER $user

ENTRYPOINT ["./startup.sh"]
```

where `./startup.sh` is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# turn on bash's job control.
set -m

# run CUPS
/usr/sbin/cupsd -f
```

I thought that was all that I needed. The container was being created with no errors and when I accessed it I could see that `lpstat` (the process initiated by `cups`) was running. But oh surprise I got when I saw that I couldn't access my API, I was getting `Error: Couldn't connect to server`.

After some reading I got to know that I was overriding the images `ENTRYPOINT` command, which was basically running PHP in this case.

I went to the images official github page and notice the command they were using was:

`CMD ["php-fpm"]`

So I thought about manually running the image's command so I could run any other commands along with it. So I modified my `Dockerfile` to have the following (just listing the last few lines I've updated):

```
COPY startup.sh startup.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "startup.sh"]

USER $user

CMD ["php-fpm"]
RUN ["bash", "startup.sh"]
```

also tried different variations of the same, like running first my bash script and then the `php-fpm`, or running `./startup.sh` instead of the way I was doing it but all of them yield the same result:

```
ERROR [app stage-0 15/15] RUN ["bash", "startup.sh"]                                                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
------
 > [app stage-0 15/15] RUN ["bash", "startup.sh"]:
0.103 Terminated
------
failed to solve: process "bash startup.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 143
make: *** [start-dev] Error 17
```

I also tried running the command as a standalone command instead of having the script, that's:

`CMD ["/usr/sbin/cupsd -f"]`

this last step allows the container to be built but when accessing the container it doesn't seem to have kicked off `cups`.

I've read that that's the way it is supposed to happen, that once the script is done then it means that there's nothing else to do, that I should add a `sleep` command or something that makes the script run forever, so I did that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# turn on bash's job control.
set -m

# run CUPS
/usr/sbin/cupsd -f

sleep infinity
```

and now my container doesn't even build. It get's stuck while executing the script (which makes sense):

```
...
 => CACHED [app stage-0 14/15] RUN ["chmod", "+x", "startup.sh"]                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [app stage-0 15/15] RUN ["bash", "startup.sh"]
```

The way I'm building the containers is (I'm using `docker-compose`):

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml up --build`

Any suggestions? how can I simply run my command when the container starts up and continue serving my stuff as usual?

Thanks.

Comment: The docker-compose.yml entrypoint works for me. ` entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "doSomething && sleep infinity"]`. The sleep keeps the container alive.

Comment: A container normally only runs a single process.  Can you run this process in a second container?  Containers also can't normally access the host's hardware, and a printer daemon might be tricky to run in Docker at all.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze. So I ended up doing that, running the process in a second container, which worked fine. I have a supervisor container in which I'm running `supervisord`, in the logs, I can see that the process is running. I've got a question though, I'm executing a print command from the container that has the API code, but I'm getting `Command lpstat -a failed: lpstat: Bad file descriptor` which makes sense, since the command  `lpstat` is now under the supervisor container. What to do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental misconception about some docker instructions, so I'll try to clarify.

### Explanations

`RUN` instructions are used to create new layers to the docker image, and whatever you start in the won't be running in the actual container. They are meant for creating and installing new stuff.

`ENTRYPOINT` is the actual script that is executed in the start of the container.

`CMD` provides parameters to the script that is set as the `ENTRYPOINT`. It's named a bit misleadingly.

Anyway, the `ENTRYPOINT` for the php base image is this: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/docker-php-entrypoint

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- php "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Which will just replace the shell with whatever is provided to it unless the `CMD` instruction starts with an option, in which case it will execute php and the options. Anyway, first you override the entrypoint with your `startup.sh`, so it will run that and only that, in the foreground (`-f`). `php-fpm` is not started anymore.

Next you did this:

```
CMD ["php-fpm"]
RUN ["bash", "startup.sh"]
```

The `CMD` part here does really nothing, since it's the same as in the base image anyway. The `RUN`, like mentioned, will sure try to run it, but only during image build time, not when the container is started. With `sleep infinity` added it will just keep the build running forever.

The rest is just variations of that.

### Solution

What you *really* need to do is have a script that starts both the `cupsd` at background and `php-fpm` in the foreground. This worked for me:

`startup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start cupsd in the background
cupsd

# Start PHP-FPM
php-fpm
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
...
COPY ./startup.sh /startup.sh
RUN chmod +x /startup.sh

CMD ["/startup.sh"]
```

Do *not* override the entrypoint.

### Bonus

Also note that whatever you do with cups, you might need to mount some extra stuff etc. See [How to run CUPS in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73789026/how-to-run-cups-in-docker).

Comment: (Alternate world view: `CMD` is the main command that's run in the container, and should generally be a complete command.  If `ENTRYPOINT` is present then it should generally be a wrapper script that expects to receive a command as arguments, like the `php-fpm` entrypoint script you quote.)

Comment: hi. thanks for the detailed explanation, learnt a lot of things. I did what you suggested and although it builds the image correctly now I'm back to the issue where php is not being served. Whenever I try to access the API I'm getting `502 Bad Gateway`